# How to sell physical products through Android and iOS apps?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, payment

I have built a Xamarin Forms mobile app for a local shop that sells physical products. The app runs on both Android and iOS (currently not published to either store). The shop's product catalog is available to view within the app and now they would like to offer their customers the ability to make purchases from within the app. They are looking for something similar to how the Starbucks app works. The customer can load their account with a certain amount of money (via credit card or PayPal) which they can use to buy physical products using the mobile app. They will not be making “in-app” types of purchases. Once the physical product has been paid for, the customer will either stop by the store and pickup the product, or the store will ship it to them.

I’ve read that there’s no way this type of app will get approved, especially by Apple. I’ve read that ApplePay will have to be involved and a 30% fee will be incurred. I’ve also read that both of those opinions are hogwash. Can someone with knowledge of current policies (as of September 2019) tell me if this can be done, and if possible, direct me to some online guidance?

Answer (score 3):

I think your app will both be accepted by Android and iOS store if you follow the policy of each platform.

For iOS, you have to follow [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines), in the section 3.1.5(a), it says:

> 3.1.5(a) Goods and Services Outside of the App: If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed outside of
>   the app, you must use purchase methods other than in-app purchase to
>   collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card
>   entry.

And in the official website: [app-store/principles-practices](https://www.apple.com/ph/ios/app-store/principles-practices/), there are several example under `84% of apps are free, and developers pay nothing to Apple` section about free or not free apps in Apple Store.

> Free with physical goods and services:
>
> These apps are free for users to download and the developer generates
>   revenue from the sale of physical goods and services, such as
>   purchasing clothing, having food delivered, or ordering a ride from a
>   transportation service. Apple receives no commission from supporting,
>   hosting, and distributing these apps, or from transactions for
>   physical goods and services in the app.

From the above information, I think apple will not collect the 30% fee if you sell physical products.

For android, I'm not so familiar with the policy of each store and I found some links that may useful to you:

[developer-content-policy](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy-print/) and this is about [Google Play Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview).

I believe your app is valid if you follow the guides of each Android store and there are a large number of apps which selling physical products running everyday.